# Error when sorting a dropdownlist on webpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, drop-down-menu

I have a webpage that won't let me sort a dropdownlist.  I have a SQLDataSource connection configured to bring up the rows Description in the table `tblCodesWorkNotRec`.  When I go to Order By and choose sort by Description, and then test the query, I'm getting an error -

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Why?

If you need to see code, what code - aspx or vb?

Here is the vb code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Partial Class TimeOffAddNoRequest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        'Once data is edited on this webpage, do not go back to first loaded data (data from gridview)
        If Page.IsPostBack = True Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim windowsLoginName As System.String = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name   'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

        Dim split As String() = Nothing
        Dim vname As String

        Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=janetdev;Initial Catalog=TimeSQL;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password")
        Dim cmd, cmd1, cmd2 As New SqlCommand
        Dim returnValue, returnValue1, returnValue2 As Object
        Dim dt As Date
        dt = Today
        MsgBox(Today)

        'Get network login name (name only)
        split = windowsLoginName.Split("\".ToCharArray)
        vname = split(1)

        'Get firstname from tblEmployees that matches login name
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT FirstName FROM tblEmployees where login = '" & vname & "'"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection

        'Get lastname from tblEmployees that matches login name
        cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT LastName FROM tblEmployees where login = '" & vname & "'"
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd1.Connection = sqlConnection

        'Get employeeid from tblEmployees that matches login name 
        cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM tblEmployees where login = '" & vname & "'"
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd2.Connection = sqlConnection

        sqlConnection.Open()

        'firstname
        returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        'lastname
        returnValue1 = cmd1.ExecuteScalar()

        'employeeid
        returnValue2 = cmd2.ExecuteScalar()

        sqlConnection.Close()

        'display firstname and lastname on screen
        TextBox3.Text = returnValue & " " & returnValue1
        TextBox4.Text = returnValue2

        'display today's date
        DateRequested.Text = dt

        'Get value of other fields 

        If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("BeginDateOff").ToString()) Then
            'Retrieving the BeginDateOff Value
            BeginDate.Text = Request.QueryString("BeginDateOff").ToString()
        End If

        If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("EndDateOff").ToString()) Then
            'Retrieving the EndDateOff Value
            EndDate.Text = Request.QueryString("EndDateOff").ToString()
        End If

        If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("BeginTimeOff").ToString()) Then
            'Retrieving the BeginTimeOff Value
            BeginTimeDD.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString("BeginTimeOff").ToString
        End If

        If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("EndTimeOff").ToString()) Then
            'Retrieving the EndTimeOff Value
            EndTimeDD.Text = Request.QueryString("EndTimeOff").ToString()
        End If

        'Retrieving the All Day Value
        AllDay.Checked = Boolean.Parse(Request.QueryString("AllDay_YesNo"))
        'AllDay.Checked = Request.QueryString("AllDay_YesNo")

        'Retrieving the WorkHoursNotRecordID
        wkid.Text = Request.QueryString("WorkHoursNotRecordID").ToString()

        If Request.QueryString("description").ToString = "Unknown" Then
            Label2.Text = "You must change the reason from Unknown."
            DropDownList2.Focus()
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'Retrieving the Description Value
            DropDownList2.Text = Request.QueryString("Description").ToString()
        End If

        BeginDate.Focus()

    End Sub
```

And here is the aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="TimeOffAddNoRequest.aspx.vb" Inherits="timework.TimeOffAddNoRequest" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolkitScriptManager" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
         style="color: #990033; font-weight: 700"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
         style="color: #000099; font-weight: 700"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <label>Employee Name:</label><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" 
         style="margin-left: 7px; font-size: medium; font-weight: 700;" 
         Width="150px" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="129px" 
         AutoPostBack="True" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <hr align="left" style="width: 791px; margin-left: 0px" />
    <label>Date Requested:<asp:TextBox ID="DateRequested" runat="server" style="margin-left: 9px; font-size: medium; font-weight: 500;" 
         Width="150px" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="True" BorderStyle="None"></asp:TextBox>
    </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <label>Begin Date Off:</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="BeginDate" runat="server" style="margin-left: 10px; font-size: medium; font-weight: 500;" 
         Width="150px" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="True" BorderStyle="Solid" 
            BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TextBox>
     <label>&nbsp; End Date Off:</label>
     <asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" runat="server" style="margin-left: 15px; font-size: medium; font-weight: 500;" 
         Width="150px" Height="22px" AutoPostBack="True" BorderStyle="Solid" 
            BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <label> All Day?</label>&nbsp;
    <asp:CheckBox ID="AllDay" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
    <label>&nbsp;&nbsp; Begin Time Off:</label>&nbsp;<label>&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="BeginTimeDD" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Time" DataValueField="Time" 
        Height="26px" Width="100px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
        &nbsp; End Time Off:</label>&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="EndTimeDD" 
            runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Time" 
            DataValueField="Time" Height="26px" Width="100px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TimeSQLConnectionString2 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Time] FROM [tblCodesTime] ORDER BY [Time]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
       <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Reason:</label>  
       <asp:DropDownList 
        ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Description" 
        DataValueField="Description" Height="26px" Width="149px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TimeSQLConnectionString1 %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [Description] FROM [tblCodesWorkNotRec] ORDER BY [Description]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:TextBox ID="wkid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Save" />
    <br />
    <br />
 </asp:Content>
```

Comment: That error is a sql server error message, not an aspx or vb message.  Could you be calling a view that has an error? Are you generating SQL?  If so, show it,.  If not show the code that generates the error and the definition of the variables in that code.

Comment: I do not have any views in my SQL database.  The field Description in tblCodesWorkRec is a text field.  I put the code in my post.  That dropdownlist (DropDownList2) is near the bottom of both.  Thanks for your help!  I redid this whole form trying to figure out where I was getting this error because debugging did not help.  Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your error is in your aspx on this line

```
SELECT [Description] FROM [tblCodesWorkNotRec] ORDER BY [Description]
```

The `order by description` is going to be what is giving you that error. You can fix this by casting to a `varchar`:

```
SELECT [Description] 
FROM [tblCodesWorkNotRec] 
ORDER BY Convert(varchar(max), [Description])
```

I'm not sure why you would want to order by a description field however.  Perhaps its best just to do away with the `order by`.  The error may also have occured on the `order by [time]` line.  But if this is a `DateTime` field its fine.  This field should probably be renamed to something that is not a keyword, like `CodeTime`

Some other notes on your code, Refactoring this is a good idea.

1. As a recommendation, I would make a *single class that talks to your database*. Dont put sql connections in your code behind, *much less in your aspx*. (if you are going to do that, pick one location, not both) This class will have all your sql and returns just the values you want.
2. *Consolidate your sql*. There is no reason to make 3 calls to the same table to get one value from each call. Make one call to get 3 things. I'm speaking of the firstname, lastname, employeeid calls.
3. *Dont put business logic in event handlers*. Notice your Page_Load method. This is an event handler. Any code that you put here cannot be called from somewhere else, so you end up copying code over and over. Simply move the calls to their own method, and call that method from Page_Load. ([GoF pattern - Facade](http://www.dofactory.com/net/facade-design-pattern))
4. *Put your UI elements in their own div tag and align them with CSS.* Get rid of (or at least think hard about) the `<br/>` and `&nbsp;` markup and use things like margin in css to move your elements around. Also move all the inline style tags to css.